# Plotting two variables as lines on the same graph with dual y-axes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have simple data set that contains data in three columns (Year, SALES, and EATR). So my intention is to put on the same graph with dual y-axes.

```
    DATA_TEST<-structure(list(Year = c("2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
                                       "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), SALES = c(82152, 
                                                                                                  90060, 84940.6666666667, 89028.6666666667, 100179.333333333, 
                                                                                                  101262.666666667, 125874, 127030, 140164.666666667, 144648, 151250
                                       ), EATR = c(10.6, 9, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9, 7.9, 
                                                   9.7)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                   ))

#Code for ploting


library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

p <- ggplot(DATA_TEST, aes(x = Year))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = SALES),alpha=2)

p


p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = EATR))
p

#Now using the sec.axis argument

p <- ggplot(DATA_TEST, aes(x = Year))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = SALES, colour = "SALES"))

# adding the EATR
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = EATR, colour = "EFFECTIVE RATE"))

# now adding the secondary axis, 
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*5, name = "EFFECTIVE RATE"))

# modifying colours and theme options
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
p <- p + labs(y = "SALES",
              x = "Year",
              colour = "Parameter")
p <- p + theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9))
p
```

So this code doesn't give me good results. My intention is to have a plot like a pic below, so can anybody help me how to fix the code above and make a plot like a pic below?

[image]

Comment: In `ggplot2`, you can only have 2 y-axes if one is a transformation of the other: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html

Comment: Here I used different variable and transformation is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a scaling factor. The key for this kind of plots is using the scaling factor to adjust the second axis. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Scale factor
sf <- max(DATA_TEST$SALES)/max(DATA_TEST$EATR)
#Plot
p <- ggplot(DATA_TEST, aes(x = Year))+
  geom_line(aes(y = SALES,,colour = "SALES",group=1),alpha=2)+
  geom_line(aes(y = EATR*sf,colour = "EFFECTIVE RATE",group=1))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./sf, name = "EFFECTIVE RATE"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))+
  labs(y = "SALES",
       x = "Year",
       colour = "Parameter")+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

Output:

[image]

And if more customization is needed:

```
#Plot 2
p <- ggplot(DATA_TEST, aes(x = Year))+
  geom_line(aes(y = SALES,,colour = "SALES",group=1),alpha=2,size=1)+
  geom_line(aes(y = EATR*sf,colour = "EFFECTIVE RATE",group=1),size=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,NA),sec.axis = sec_axis(~./sf, name = "EFFECTIVE RATE"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))+
  labs(y = "SALES",
       x = "Year",
       colour = "Parameter")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]